# Textfilter with wildcards no results

Tags: filter, library, dataview

I followed this tutorial [SharePoint 2010 - Configure textFilter to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fngmk.png)
but no matter what I search for (write a text, then press enter), I get no results. After a great deal of trial & error I can't find why...Although, I have to say our site is in Sharepoint 2016.
[image]

My .aspx page is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="WebPartPages" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SPSWC" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server"></SharePoint:CssLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" localizable="false" language="javascript" name="core.js">
</SharePoint:ScriptLink>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server" id="SPWebPartManager"><SPWebPartConnections>
<WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection ID="g_9D4EC076BCC94517A729B8A0C6F989B7" ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Parameter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_d885505e_5b59_4cfd_beed_9385c1fa97ab" ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="g_a739b808_b59a_4f62_aa80_957df4b41c23">

<WebPartPages:transformablefiltervaluestoparameterstransformer ProviderFieldNames="$Resources:spscore,DwpTextFilterTitle" ConsumerFieldNames="Param1" />
</WebPartPages:spwebpartconnection>
</SPWebPartConnections>
</WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>
<SPSWC:SPSlicerTextWebPart runat="server" MaximumCharacters="255" RequireSelection="False" FilterMainControlWidthPixels="0" FilterName="$Resources:spscore,DwpTextFilterTitle" Title="$Resources:spscore,DwpTextFilterTitle" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="$Resources:spscore,DwpTextFilterDescription" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="" PartOrder="0" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" TitleIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_a739b808_b59a_4f62_aa80_957df4b41c23" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{a739b808-b59a-4f62-aa80-957df4b41c23}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></SPSWC:SPSlicerTextWebPart>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" Title="ΕΛΠΕ φωτογραφίες" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" ListName="{1E8BF9A6-F27B-4EE8-84EF-FCE2866353E8}" Default="FALSE" DisplayName="ΕΛΠΕ φωτογραφίες" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{D885505E-5B59-4CFD-BEED-9385C1FA97AB}" id="g_d885505e_5b59_4cfd_beed_9385c1fa97ab" viewcontenttypeid="0x" __designer:customxsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl">
<XmlDefinition>
    <View Name="{E633F55A-55AB-4510-9E2C-0FD4148D8576}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Scope="Recursive" DisplayName="All Pictures" Url="/sites/devtest/Gallery/Forms/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/plicon.png?rev=40">
        <Query>
            <Where>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                    <Value Type="Text">{Param1}</Value>
                </Contains>
            </Where>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
            <FieldRef Name="ImageSize"/>
            <FieldRef Name="FileSizeDisplay"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
            <FieldRef Name="RequiredField" Explicit="TRUE"/>
            <FieldRef Name="PreviewOnForm" Explicit="TRUE"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x0391__x03c0__x03bf__x03c3__x03c4__x03bf__x03bb__x03ad__x03b1__x03c2_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x0395__x03c4__x03b1__x03b9__x03c1__x03b5__x03af__x03b1_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x0397__x03bc__x03b5__x03c1__x03bf__x03bc__x03b7__x03bd__x03af__x03b1__x0020__x03b1__x03c0__x03bf_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x0397__x03bc__x03b5__x03c1__x03bf__x03bc__x03b7__x03bd__x03af__x03b1__x0020__x03ad__x03c9__x03c2_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x039a__x03b1__x03c4__x03b7__x03b3__x03bf__x03c1__x03af__x03b1_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x039b__x03ae__x03c8__x03b7_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x038c__x03bd__x03bf__x03bc__x03b1__x0020_CD_x0020__x002d__x0020_DVD"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x03a0__x03c1__x03cc__x03c3__x03c9__x03c0__x03b1_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x03a4__x03bf__x03c0__x03bf__x03b8__x03b5__x03c3__x03af__x03b1_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="_x03a4__x03cd__x03c0__x03bf__x03c2_"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Watermark"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Original"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Resized"/>
            <FieldRef Name="FileType"/>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js|callout.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
    </View>
</XmlDefinition>
<parameterbindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="None" DefaultValue=""/>
</parameterbindings></WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to say I have NOT used SP2016. However, there a few things I would like to share when it comes to searching within SP.

First off, depending on where your search is located within the folder structure your results can be limited. Remember, from the point of search, you can only go downwards... you cannot search up and then back down a neighboring branch.

Secondly, using operators to define your search can help. SP supports AND, OR (space between words is the same as this), NOT, + (similar to AND), - (similar to NOT), plus all the common mathematical ones, =, <, >, <=, >=, <>, .., etc.

Wildcards are great, but you also need to make sure you are using them correctly. It should be something like heli* not *copter. SP restricts wildcards usage to be after a few characters, and never before.

Nothing really jumps out at me in the code you posted... but does the standard OOB (Out of the Box) search functionality within libraries work?

Most of the things you can do with search can be found on the [MS Office Support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-for-content-92fb9f82-2825-4e69-a3b5-34c294bc1961)

I don't know if this helps... Good luck.